# Chinese text not displaying properly on web page

Tags: html, character-encoding, cjk

I am adding some Chinese text to a primarily English web page and am having trouble getting the characters to display properly. I've got the encoding set to UTF-8 in the meta content type tag, and I am copying/pasting the Chinese I was sent from a Word document. The text is still rendering as follows:

ÁπÅÈ´î‰∏≠ÊñáÁâà

rather than in Chinese characters:

繁體中文版

I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I'm lost as to how to make this happen.

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Look like the page is still in Mac Roman encoding.

Comment: Hmmm. How can I get it set to the proper encoding? Thanks

Comment: Please right click on the generated web page, View Source, and paste the relevant source code here.

Comment: @KennyTM: Here's the code of a stripped-down test page:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Test</title>
<link href="/css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
<p>ÂïÜÂä°ÊãìÂ±ïÔºà‰∏≠ÂõΩÂå∫Ôºâ‰∏ª‰ªª</p>
</div>

It's not pasting properly.

Answer (score 2):

just because the meta tag says that the encoding is UTF8, doesn't mean that the content (file) itself is in UTF8. I mean, if you have a file index.html, the file itself should be encoded as utf8.

To change the encoding of a file in lunix, you can use this command

```
iconv --from-code=ISO-8859-1 --to-code=UTF-8 ./index.html > ./newIndex.html
```

but i guess that you are working with windows... and the only way i know change the encoding in windows is the Notepad++

Hope this helps

Comment: That makes sense. I've got my default page encoding set to UTF-8 when a new document is created in Dreamweaver (I'm on a mac) but it still doesn't seem to be encoding properly.

Comment: hmm one way to find out the "real" encoding of your page is to open it in firefox and change the encoding (View->Character Encoding) until you see the Chinese characters. Be careful when you do copy/paste, because when you copy some text in Big5 into a UTF8 file for exemple, the system won't make the conversion automatically. The correct way to proceed is: Find out the original encoding of your source, convert it somehow to UTF8 (or UTF16), then put it in your .html file. Good Luck