# Display Chinese Japanese characters in WebPage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, culture, html-encode

I was developing MVC3 application. In my Application, there will be a number of Chinese and Japanese characters. When showing those characters on the webpage I was getting some weird characters appears on the screen instead of Chinese or Japanese characters. Can anyone tell me how can i show above mentioned language characters without any issue on the page.

**I have Tried the below way**

```
font-family: Arial Unicode MS, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  // But this way didn't help me out.
```

Thanks

Comment: what's your charset? you can try this <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: @bastianonm. Even I was using the charset what you posted only. still i was getting weird characters instead of original characters. Ex:
 
̆̄æ̌̇æ̆æ̆®̇

Comment: I found another question like your: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578100/chinese-text-not-displaying-properly-on-web-page

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ISO character sets, you need to use the right one for these languages
[Character Sets](http://html-codes.net/html/character-sets/)

Or you can just simply set character set to UTF-8 and not worry about the language on the page it self. If you're still seeing weird characters, might be that you somehow overwrite the encoding, or perhaps have a malformed HTML code.

Cheers,
Deadpool